# DDL Trigger which grants permission to new created users

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I got a question, is there a possibilty, that a DDL Trigger can grant roles right after the user is created.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DDL_TRIGGER
AFTER CREATE ROLE ON DATABASE
```

And after that, the trigger should grant the new user with some roles.

For example:

```
BEGIN
GRANT Resourse to *new created user*;
GRANT CONNECT to *new created user*;
```

I use oracle database.

Thank you guys,
Marki

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734309/oracle-is-it-possible-to-create-a-role-in-a-trigger

Comment: Thank you Moudiz

Unfortunately in my situation the role is already created.
The trigger should only add certain roles to the user, which was just created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_CREATE_USER 
    AFTER CREATE ON DATABASE
    WHEN (ora_dict_obj_type = 'USER')
BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT RESOURCE TO '||ora_dict_obj_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT CONNECT TO '||ora_dict_obj_name;

END;
/
```

Check [Using Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2014) for further details.

Please check also this post: [How do I create a Oracle trigger that grants permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262539/how-do-i-create-a-oracle-trigger-that-grants-permissions?rq=1) - perhaps my solution does not work.